# Theoretical returns of Short Straddle in an efficient Options Market

Tags: options, black-scholes, theory

**Assumptions**:

1. Market is efficient
2. All assumptions of BS Model apply
3. Implied Volatility predicted using BS model is same as actual volatility in future. Needless to say that the volatility is constant throughout the position period.

**Description**:

In BS model, option seller of a single strike itself makes a risk free return in the long run.
Since in Short stradddle, two options are sold at same strike, the IV of the portfolio would be double that of actual volatility experienced in market. This implies that short straddle sellers can make more money than risk free return in the long run.

**Question**:
By theory how much a short straddle seller can make in the long run?

Comment: In theory you have answered your own question; looking at assumption numero 3.

Comment: do you mean straddle seller makes 1x volatility amount?